# What's so good about the Bazaar Bargain?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

When I see it on TF2 wiki, I could only find info about its disadvantages from missing people. What makes the Bazaar Bargain so good that I would rather pick that than the stock sniper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bazaar Bargain is one of those items that just **depend on your playstyle and skill**.If you keep running around getting one-two headshots and then die it is pretty much useless to you,but if you keep getting in good positions with nice headshots and killstreaks you will have a nice bonus without even noticing the disadvantage.

The -40% **starting** charge rate sounds like a big disadvantage,but really it is not.It just means that after you set up in a nice position you will have to wait 4.6 seconds before the first shot instead the 3.3s , which is negligible considering the benefit.

Now if you ignore the starting charge,you can see on this graph the benefits.
You can also ignore Huntsman since it is more of a mid-range weapon due the high projectile drop.

Also note that the graph ignores the de-buff of the bazaar for the first shot completely,meaning that the **charge time for 0 heads is actually 4.6s** but rest of the values stay the same.

[image]

And before July 10th the starting charge rate was -20% which was like 0.8s,really negligible.

Comment: To add to this already fantastic answer, headshots from either rifle with no charge kills 5 of the 9 classes in one shot. Though the bazaar bargain is not a particularly popular weapon, it's certainly by no means underpowered in the hands of someone who can consistently headshot.

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile the chart here with your words... the first point on the chart for the BB is at 3.3s, you state that you have to "wait 4.7 seconds" for the first shot (i.e. zero heads). The chart seems to indicate it behaves exactly like the normal sniper rifle with no heads. Which is it?

Comment: The chart uses pure rifle stats(without de-buffs) in order to pre-calculate all the exponential values.In this case(without de-buff) the starting charge is same as it is with ordinary rifle 3.3s.If you add -40% de-buff on the first shot you get ~4.7s(which is the actual time for 0 heads)...Edited the answer since it really does make the graph look wrong without explanation.